# How to display exception message from spring rest api to angular component using ngrx effects?

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot, ngrx-store

I am having a sample application spring boot with angular 8, i am trying to display an exception message received from rest api to angular app. But i don't know how to subscribe and display through component.

Here is my

> component.ts code

```
constructor(private store: Store<ApplicationState>) {}

this.store.dispatch(new SaveApplicationUserAction(applicationUser));
var err = this.store.select(s => s.applicationUsers.applicationUsers);
console.log(err);
```

I am dispatching an action `SaveApplicationUserAction` which is configured using ngrx

> action.ts code

```
export class SaveApplicationUserAction implements Action {
    readonly type = SAVE_APPLICATION_USER;

    constructor(public payload: ApplicationUser) { }
}

export class SaveApplicationUserSuccessAction implements Action {
    readonly type = SAVE_APPLICATION_USER_SUCCESS;

    constructor(public payload: ApplicationUser) { }
}

export class HttpErrorAction implements Action {
    readonly type = HTTP_ERROR;

    constructor(public payload: string) { }
}
```

> effects.ts code

```
@Effect()
        saveApplicationUser$ = this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(actions.SAVE_APPLICATION_USER),
            exhaustMap((action: actions.SaveApplicationUserAction) =>
            this.userService.saveApplicationUser(action.payload).pipe(
                // user tap to set my cookie and achieve my side effect
                tap(user => {
                    console.log(user);
                }),
                // use map without any side effect
                map((user: any) => new actions.SaveApplicationUserSuccessAction(user)),
                catchError(error => of(new actions.HttpErrorAction(error))
            )
            )
            )
        );
```

> reducer.ts code

```
class ApplicationUserState {
        applicationUsers: ApplicationUser[];
        applicationUser: ApplicationUser;
        hasError: boolean;
        errMessage: string;
}
const initialState: ApplicationUserState = {
    applicationUsers: [],
    applicationUser: null,
    hasError: false,
    errMessage: null
};

export function applicationUserReducer(state = initialState, action: formActions.ApplicationUserActions) {
    console.log(state);
    switch (action.type) {
        case formActions.SAVE_APPLICATION_USER_SUCCESS: {
            return state = {
                applicationUsers: [...state.applicationUsers, action.payload],
                applicationUser: action.payload,
                hasError: state.hasError,
                errMessage: state.errMessage
            };
        }
        case formActions.HTTP_ERROR: {
            const httpErrorAction :formActions.HttpErrorAction = action as formActions.HttpErrorAction;
            return Object.assign({}, state, {error: httpErrorAction.payload});
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
  }
```

I am having an exception occured so i am return a `ResponseEntity` from spring rest api as

```
if(ex.getMessage().contains("ConstraintViolationException")) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage(ex.getMessage()), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
```

I don't have idea how to check the status code of http and how to display the exception message to the front user through component using ngrx effects, actions and reducer. Can anyone help me on this problem or any suggestions or links to refer.

Comment: you should write a selector for `errMessage` to show it.

Comment: But i need to display the catch exception message in the screen once the action is dispatch using store.select i need to get the message which i am send through the HttpErrorAction